# Starting out with Python Program 4-9

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to design a count-controlled loop with the for statement. I have copied the example program in the text perfectly (or so I thought). I tried to run this program, but I keep getting a syntax error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
# This program converts the speeds 60 kph
# through 130 kph (in 10 kph increments)
# to mph.

START_SPEED = 60            # Starting speed
END_SPEED = 131             # Ending speed
INCREMENT = 10              # Speed increment
CONVERSION_FACTOR = 0.6214  # Conversion factor

# Print the table headings.
print('KPH\tMPH')
print('--------------')

# Print the speeds.
for kph in range(START_SPEED, END_SPEED, INCREMENT)
    mph = kph * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    print(kph, '\t', format(mph, '.1f'))
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Python programming! _"but I keep getting a syntax error"_: where? What's the error? Be descriptive. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking a `:`

```
...

for kph in range(START_SPEED, END_SPEED, INCREMENT):
    mph = kph * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    ...
```

With the `:`

I get

```
KPH MPH
--------------
60   37.3
70   43.5
80   49.7
90   55.9
100      62.1
110      68.4
120      74.6
130      80.8
```